# int_months_between for weeks in impala?

Tags: cloudera, impala

What would be the best solution for `int_months_between`in **weeks** for Impala?
Would I have to work with `Invervals` or what is the best recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `datediff` function, which returns difference in days, and then to divide the result with 7. It will not be precise in terms of business weeks, and there might be some ambiguous results at the beginning or end of the year, but in general it should do the trick. This is function signature for Impala 5.8.x:

`datediff(timestamp enddate, timestamp startdate)`